# ioncube install centos 6 zend error

Tags: php, centos6, ioncube

i currently have vestacp installed on a centos 6 webserver,

zend is installed and i believe ioncube is installed however ioncube states that it is infact not installed.

machine:

```
Linux fellio.example.com 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 18 19:25:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

here is my php info which indicates ioncube loaded:

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.29RC1 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2016 10:20:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v6.0.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

here is my modules:

```
ls /usr/lib64/php/modules/
bcmath.so    dom.so       gettext.so  ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so  mysqli.so     pdo_sqlite.so  shmop.so      sysvmsg.so    wddx.so       xsl.so
bz2.so       exif.so      gmp.so      json.so                    mysqlnd.so    phar.so        simplexml.so  sysvsem.so    xmlreader.so  ZendGuardLoader.so
calendar.so  fileinfo.so  iconv.so    ldap.so                    mysql.so      posix.so       soap.so       sysvshm.so    xmlrpc.so     zip.so
ctype.so     ftp.so       imap.so     mbstring.so                pdo_mysql.so  pspell.so      sockets.so    tidy.so       xml.so
curl.so      gd.so        intl.so     mcrypt.so                  pdo.so        recode.so      sqlite3.so    tokenizer.so  xmlwriter.so
```

php.d output:

```
00-Ioncube.ini   20-dom.ini       20-gmp.ini       20-mcrypt.ini   20-recode.ini     20-sysvmsg.ini    20-xmlwriter.ini   30-wddx.ini
20-bcmath.ini    20-exif.ini      20-iconv.ini     20-mysqlnd.ini  20-shmop.ini      20-sysvsem.ini    20-xsl.ini         30-xmlreader.ini
20-bz2.ini       20-fileinfo.ini  20-imap.ini      20-pdo.ini      20-simplexml.ini  20-sysvshm.ini    30-mysqli.ini      30-xmlrpc.ini
20-calendar.ini  20-ftp.ini       20-intl.ini      20-phar.ini     20-soap.ini       20-tidy.ini       30-mysql.ini       40-json.ini
20-ctype.ini     20-gd.ini        20-ldap.ini      20-posix.ini    20-sockets.ini    20-tokenizer.ini  30-pdo_mysql.ini   40-zip.ini
20-curl.ini      20-gettext.ini   20-mbstring.ini  20-pspell.ini   20-sqlite3.ini    20-xml.ini        30-pdo_sqlite.ini  ZendGuard.ini
```

00-Ioncube.ini output:

```
cat 00-Ioncube.ini
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
```

ZendGuard.ini output:

```
 cat ZendGuard.ini
; Enable Zend Guard extension
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so
zend_loader.enable=1
```

php.ini:

located on pastebin as to big to post on here: http://pastebin.com/MWS9fQ8b

error:

```
 service vesta restart
Stopping vesta-nginx:                                      [  OK  ]
Stopping vesta-php:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting vesta-nginx:                                      [  OK  ]
Starting vesta-php: Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so: undefined symbol: zend_execute_ex
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

error log shows:

```
sh: gradm: command not found
```

when using the loader-wizard to install ioncube i get the following error:

```
    Please note that the following problems currently exist with the ionCube Loader installation:
    The following ini files could not be found by the Wizard: /etc/php.ini,/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini,/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,/etc/php.d/20-gmp.ini,/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini,/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini,/etc/php.d/20-ldap.ini,/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini,/etc/php.d/20-mcrypt.ini,/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini,/etc/php.d/20-pspell.ini,/etc/php.d/20-recode.ini,/etc/php.d/20-shmop.ini,/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,/etc/php.d/20-soap.ini,/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,/etc/php.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,/etc/php.d/20-sysvsem.ini,/etc/php.d/20-sysvshm.ini,/etc/php.d/20-tidy.ini,/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,/etc/php.d/30-mysql.ini,/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini,/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini,/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,/etc/php.d/30-xmlrpc.ini,/etc/php.d/40-json.ini,/etc/php.d/40-zip.ini
    This may be due to server restrictions in place.
    The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration.
Please also note the following:
The correct loader for your system has been found at /home/admin/web/websiteguardtest.tk/public_html/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so. You may wish to copy the loader from /home/admin/web/websiteguardtest.tk/public_html/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so to /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

.

i disabled open_base dir in the template files associated as i thought this could be the issue but its not, i am not sure what the issue is with ioncube and my vestacp machine any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: any news about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile ioncube or reinstall it correctly.

To have a hint about whet went wrong or what dependency is missing, just type

ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so